# Observable custom prototype function, is "not a function"

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, observable, angular7

We created an operator function to unsubscribe from any subscriptions when components get destroyed. We are using the ng-take-until-destroy library to help with this.

This worked perfectly fine before upgrading to Angular 6 / 7

```
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/internal/Observable";
import { untilDestroyed } from "ngx-take-until-destroy";

declare module "rxjs/internal/Observable" {
    interface Observable<T> {
        subscribeUntilDestroy: (target, action?, error?, complete?) => Subscription;
    }
}

Observable.prototype.subscribeUntilDestroy = function(target, action?, error?, complete?): Subscription {
    return this.pipe(untilDestroyed(target)).subscribe(action, error, complete);
};
```

It should work just as if we were using "subscribe", but the browser javascript console errors saying that "subscribeUntilDestroy" is not a function.

Any thoughts?

Here's how we are trying to use it:

```
let interval = observableInterval(SessionService.MAX_IDLE_TIME).pipe(delay(5000));
        interval.subscribeUntilDestroy(
            this,
            value => this.monitor()
        );
```

This seems to be an issue with our environment

Comment: You noted, _"before upgrading to Angular 6 / 7"_. This means your project should now be working with RxJS 6. In the latter version, user-defined observable prototype operators should be rewritten as a function compatible with being passed into `pipe()`. [The RxJS migration guide has an example.](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) In your case, the final result should look something like: `observableInternal(...).pipe(delay(5000), untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe()`.

Comment: @miqh I get we can write it that way, but we wanted to make it an extension of the observable subscribe though, so we can use .subscribeUntilDestroy() as noted above, instead of .subscribe and have to pipe that everywhere. We wanted to be able to write it one spot and forget it, instead of having to remember it on every subscription.

Comment: @miqh We've re-written all of our observables to pipe, then subscribe afterwards. The subscribe method is what we want to extend so that we don't have to do the "untilDestroy(this)" pipe everywhere, and it just happens automatically. We feel it's just excessive code, and if we got it working in angular 5, then we should be able to get it to work in 6 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The import for the Observable had to be just "rxjs" instead of the internal one.